# Unable to load unrecognised application type Browser Launch

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am having problems while trying to import a release to my bp.

The error which appeared is:

> "An error occurred while attempting to import the release. Unable to load
>   unrecognised application type Browser Launch"

This release was correctly opened on another computer.

Does anyone know why it happens or how to fix it?

Comment: are the Blue Prism installations different versions? can you check and confirm?

Comment: fixed. I was using version 6 and the release was made in 6.6. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue crops up primarily when attempting to import releases to & from different versions of Blue Prism.

You really should only import releases into Blue Prism environments running the same version of Blue Prism as the environment from which the release was generated in.